# conditional statement working incorrectly-python

Tags: python, class, conditional-statements

I have two scripts: rank.py and elo_7.py. The elo script pulls info from rank.

In elo_7.py:

```
...

elif player_1.age or player_2.age > 50 and abs(player_1.age-player_2.age) > 10:
    (make some adjustment)
```

In rank.py:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name,age,rank_nogi,record,weight,school):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.rank_nogi=rank_nogi
        self.record=record
        self.weight=weight 
        self.school=school

player_1=Player('John',20,1600,0,91,'SJJ')
player_2=Player('Sally',29,1650,0,81,'SJJ')
```

Since the age difference is only 9 years and neither player is over 50 the `elif` statement should not execute and yet it does. Could someone please explain why?

On a side note, if I change the `or` to `and` then it will not execute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

Its the way you are grouping the conditional statements. You need to change it to:

```
elif (player_1.age > 50) or (player_2.age > 50) and abs(player_1.age-player_2.age) > 
10:
```

It evaluates the conditionals short-circuited meaning that since `player_1.age1` is on the left-side of the OR, and player_1.age is non-null (evaluates to true) that the elif is evaluated as true before doing the other checks. See section 3.8 of this https://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook004.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the way you are grouping things. Its always evaluating to True and not doing what you expect. You can use the "any" operator to avoid writing the conditional multiple times.

```
elif any(x > 50 for x in [player_1.age, player_2.age]) and abs(player_1.age-player_2.age) > 10:
```